# Named pipes underlying stream

Tags: c#, named-pipes

When using Named Pipes with c#. If we use a using statement to create the client and server pipe, then connect a streamReader and streamWriter to it. Does the streamReader and StreamWriter also get disposed when the namedPipe gets disposed (at the end of the using statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Streams do not magically keep track of every `StreamReader` or `StreamWriter` instance that use them. This is true of any stream, not just named pipes.

```
var stream = ...;
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
stream.Dispose();
// reader is not disposed here
```

However, by default, disposing a `StreamReader` or `StreamWriter` disposes the stream they were constructed with:

```
var stream = ...;
using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    // ...
// stream is disposed here
```

That is, unless you constructed them by passing `true` to their `leaveOpen` parameter (that's the last one, below):

```
var stream = ...;
using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding, false, 4096, true))
    // ...
// stream is not disposed here
```

In other words, by default, readers or writers *own* their streams, which means they are responsible for closing them when they are themselves closed. Readers and writers that do not own their stream will only flush their internal buffers when disposed, but leave the stream otherwise untouched.

Comment: ok thanks for response. What would be the proper way to dispose a stream reader/writer that is connected to a named pipe stream. If I dispose the stream reader/writer it disconnects the pipe entirely, so i wouldn't be able to make multiple reads/writes

Comment: Open your reader/writer with the `leaveOpen` parameter set to true. That way, disposing the reader/writer will flush all remaining data down the pipe but leave it open. That way, you get proper cleanup but you get to keep the pipe for later use.

Comment: Thanks @etienne that worked. I left the stream open and dispose it once done using the named pipe